# Remove duplicates but retain sequence

Tags: python

I'm trying to reduce a string with duplicates however I do not want to create a set. For example

```
mystring = 'TTTTTPPPTPTTTTPPPPPPPPP'
```

The sequence of the letters is 'TPTPTP', so I need a resulting string of

```
newstring = 'TPTPTP'
```

I'm sure there is an easy one-liner but its evading me

Comment: How did you non one-liner go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zip each character with the one before and take those which are different:

```
>>> a
'TTTTTPPPTPTTTTPPPPPPPPP'
>>> ''.join(i for i, j in zip(a, '\0' + a) if i != j)
'TPTPTP'
```

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `itertools.groupby`.

```
>>> mystring = 'TTTTTPPPTPTTTTPPPPPPPPP'
>>> groups = [x for x, y in itertools.groupby(mystring)]
>>> groups
['T', 'P', 'T', 'P', 'T', 'P']
>>> ''.join(groups)
TPTPTP
```

[Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: Can you add a lot more details so that this isn't a link-only answer without even a link?

Comment: Nice answer.  This is one of the canonical use cases for *itertools.groupby* and is reminiscent of the ``uniq`` command-line tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expressions if you feel like it.

```
>>> import re
>>> mystring = 'TTTTTPPPTPTTTTPPPPPPPPP'
>>> ''.join(re.findall(r'(.)\1*', mystring))
'TPTPTP'
```

That looks for any character, followed by the same found character zero or more times.